# Guardar resultados de una query en una lista o array de objetos en python

Tags: python, array, arraylist

estoy intentando guardar los resultados de una una query en MySql y transformarlos en un array de objetos de python para luego recorrerlo y hacer diferentes operaciones sobre cada elemento

la query la realizo perfectamente pero no se como pasar cada fila a un elemento del diccionario conservando los nombres de las columnas.

Ej. Si la query es:

`SELECT nombre_columna_1, nombre_columna_1, nombre_columna_1 from miTabla`

deseo que el array se guarde asi (la idea es guardar todos los datos que resulten de la query, ya sea 1 o 100, etc:

````
              { 
                nombre_columna_1: '*dato1*',
                nombre_columna_2: '*dato2*',
                nombre_columna_3: '*dato3*',
              },
              { 
                nombre_columna_1: '*dato1*',
                nombre_columna_2: '*dato2*',
                nombre_columna_2: '*dato3*',
              },```
````

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de la línea que hace la consulta SQL, en qué variable almacena el resultado, y muestra cuál es el contenido de esa variable. Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir esta información

Comment: Acare un poco mas respecto a la query que estoy haciendo, quizas ayude un poco

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo que necesitas mediante una comprenhension list (suponiendo que estás usando fetchall).

```py
# ...
>>> cur.execute('SELECT dato1, dato2, dato3 from miTabla')
>>> res = cur.fetchall()  # [('dato1a', 'dato2a', 'dato3a'), ('dato1b', 'dato2b', 'dato3b'), ('dato1c', 'dato2c', 'dato3c')]
>>> list_dict: [{'dato1': d1, 'dato2': d2, 'dato3': d3} for d1, d2, d3 in res]
>>> list_dict
>>> [{'dato1': 'dato1a', 'dato2': 'dato2a', 'dato3': 'dato3a'}, {'dato1': 'dato1b', 'dato2': 'dato
2b', 'dato3': 'dato3b'}, {'dato1': 'dato1c', 'dato2': 'dato2c', 'dato3': 'dato3c'}]

## esto sería el equivalente en un for
# list_dict = []
# for d1, d2, d3 in res:
#     list_dict.append({'dato1': d1, 'dato2': d2, 'dato3': d3} )
# >>> list_dict
# >>> [{'dato1': 'dato1a', 'dato2': 'dato2a', 'dato3': 'dato3a'}, {'dato1': 'dato1b', 'dato2': 'dato2b', 'dato3': 'dato3b'}, {'dato1': 'dato1c', 'dato2': 'dato2c', 'dato3': 'dato3c'}]
```